# Covert string to yaml and return response in flask

Tags: python, flask

I am using flask to return response for the following yaml string data stored in database

`str = "db:\nname:dbname"`

Here \n is new line character.

I tried

`data = yaml.safe_load(str)`

returns error

> yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
> in "", line 2, column 1: name:dbname

`response=yaml.dump(str))`

in get but response is

`"db:name:dbname"`

in a single line string. Instead of following

```
db:
  name:
      dbname
```

How to get correct response and also validate database stored string whether correct or not?

Comment: I think if you want to show it in `HTML` you should use the `<br>` element for this purpose. But I believe, it's better to handle it with javascript.

Comment: @ImanShafiei Not possible here. Its bounded by data provided.

Comment: Ok So, if you want to show it on HTML, I think you should replace the `\n` characters with the `<br>` tag.

Comment: Whats the point of converting to yaml then?

Comment: I'm just telling you that you can't show `yaml` in `html` without using tags. Look at this script (it's for swagger YAML) https://gist.github.com/oseiskar/dbd51a3727fc96dcf5ed189fca491fb3